# How to select a random element from an array with two variables

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have created a program and I would like to select a random element from an array, however I need to make sure that that element is not of a certain type. To show what type it is, when i created the array i assigned 3 numbers. 0=normal human, 1=Zombie, 2= cat. The array initially spawns a 10 * 10 array of normal humans however when you right click you can spawn a zombie. The function then runs when the play hits a start button(info on function not needed for question). If no zombie is selected i want it to create a random one from a human. This is the code so far:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                if (canZombSpawn == false) {
                    ZombieSpreader(playingGrid[x][y].face, playingGrid[x][y].typeOfChar);
                } else {
                    do {
                        t = (int) ((Math.random() * 10));
                        p = (int) ((Math.random() * 10));

                    } while (playingGrid[t][p].typeOfChar != 0);
                    image = new ImageIcon("zombie.gif");
                    playingGrid[t][p].face.setIcon(image);
                    playingGrid[t][p].typeOfChar = 1;
                    ZombieSpreader(playingGrid[x][y].face, playingGrid[x][y].typeOfChar);
                }
            }
        }
```

`ZombieSpreader` is the method (not important)

`playingGrid` is the array and `typeOfChar` is the type of character.

Any help is much appreciated thanks =)

Comment: What's with `java` and `javascript` tag?

Comment: Please note that Java and JavaScript are different languages-- your question is about Java.

Comment: Sorry, I have _no_ idea what you're asking for.

Comment: What array is `playingGrid` of? What does `ZombieSpreader` method do? Why are they not important if they constitute more than half of the code above?

Comment: So, you want to be able to filter the array so you can identify the locations of the humans and then randomly select one?

Comment: @MadProgrammer precisely

Comment: I'd be a whole lot easier if you used actually objects, which maintained their location on the grid and you used `List` instead of arrays

Answer (score 1):

This is not particularly efficient, but it should work for your needs:

```
int[][] data = new int[10][10];
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
        data[row][col] = rnd.nextInt(4);
    }
}

Random rndFind = new Random();
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
boolean found = false;
do {
    row = rndFind.nextInt(10);
    col = rndFind.nextInt(10);
    if (data[row][col] == 0) {
        found = true;
    }
} while (!found);
System.out.println("Found human @ " + row + "x" + col);
```

Basically, it just generates two random indices (row/col) and checks the value within the array, if it's a "human" it exits the loop, otherwise it tries again.

It would be easier to generate a more efficient method if each element was a self contained object (which knew its position and type) and you used `List` instead of arrays

... Because I can't resist having a play ...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    public enum CharacterType {
        HUMAN, ZOMBIE, CAT;

        private static Random rnd = new Random();

        public static CharacterType random() {
            switch (rnd.nextInt(3)) {
                case 0:
                    return HUMAN;
                case 1:
                    return ZOMBIE;
                default:
                    return CAT;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class CharacterEnity {

        private int gridX, gridY;
        private CharacterType type;

        public CharacterEnity(CharacterType type, int gridX, int gridY) {
            this.gridX = gridX;
            this.gridY = gridY;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public int getGridX() {
            return gridX;
        }

        public int getGridY() {
            return gridY;
        }

        public CharacterType getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setGridX(int gridX) {
            this.gridX = gridX;
        }

        public void setGridY(int gridY) {
            this.gridY = gridY;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is the main collection...
        List<CharacterEnity> entities = new ArrayList<>(100);

        // This is just setup...
        List<Integer> rows = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}));
        List<Integer> columns = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}));

        Collections.shuffle(rows);
        List<Integer> unusedColumns = new ArrayList<>(10);
        while (!rows.isEmpty()) {
            Collections.shuffle(columns);
            unusedColumns.addAll(columns);
            int row = rows.remove(0);
            while (!unusedColumns.isEmpty()) {
                CharacterType type = CharacterType.random();
                entities.add(new CharacterEnity(type, unusedColumns.remove(0), row));
            }
        }
        // End setup...

        List<CharacterEnity> humans = entities.stream().filter(e -> e.getType() == CharacterType.HUMAN).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Found " + humans.size() + " humans");
        Collections.shuffle(humans);
        CharacterEnity turn = humans.get(0);
        System.out.println("Turning human @ " + turn.getGridX() + "x" + turn.getGridY());
    }

}
```

Okay, so basically this defines a `CharacterEntity` class which knows where it is on the grid (you could have a `Map` to map a entity to a position as well, depending on your needs)

It filters the `List` of entities to only get the human characters, it then shuffles this `List` to randomise it, grabs the first element and turns them